# How old did Adam and Eve look when they were created?

Tags: creation, adam-and-eve

This might impossible to answer but...

**How old did Adam and Eve look when they were created**? Certainly they were old not babies, considering Adam walked and talked and named animals and had sex with Eve. Is there any way of knowing this?

> **Genesis 2:5-7 ESV -** When no bush of the field was yet in the land and no small plant of the field had yet sprung up—for the Lord God had not caused it to rain on the land, and there was no man to work the ground, and a mist was going up from the land and was watering the whole face of the ground— **then the Lord God formed the man of dust from the ground and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life, and the man became a living creature**.

---

EDIT: I am assuming a plain interpretation of Genesis here. That Adam and Eve were formed as adults in a small amount of time by God.

Comment: I think you mean to ask, "how old did they appear to be when created". And you might want to narrow your question to something like, "for young earth creationists...." because the answer is going to be dependent on your view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the indicators that you mention make their age more than 5 years old,  and based on the birth of Seth less than 130 years old.

> ... since Genesis 5:3 informs us that Adam was 130 years old when Seth was born, it is obvious that Adam and Eve could not have been in the Garden of Eden any longer than 130 years!

<sub>[How Long Were Adam and Eve in the Garden of Eden?](http://www.apologeticspress.org/apcontent.aspx?category=11&article=157) End of the 5th paragraph</sub>

The first 5 paragraphs of this link talk about how long they were in the Garden of Eden, and I think that is really going to be part of this answer no matter how you look at it.

Back to the indicators,

- walking
- talking
- naming animals

these things can be done by a 5 year old (give or take a year or more)

- falling in love
- being lonely (or needing a helper, as indicated as the reason for God to create Eve)

These things can happen in a young child or adolescent depending on your definition of falling in love,  I would say that because God created one for the other that they could have instantly fallen in love, seeing that they literally completed each other.

My vote is that this happened in early adulthood when Adam was still young enough to till the earth.

---

**I believe that these things happened through the stages of life** (like growing up), much as they do for us, so it is entirely possible that He created Adam and Eve as Children or even took care of them as Babies until they were old enough to thrive in the garden.

I don't think that these things all happened in one day, I think it happened over an extended length of time where Adam and Eve developed skills and knowledge and other things they would need to survive on their own (*when they left the garden*)

Unfortunately, this is more "my opinion" than biblical fact.

Comment: Would you be able to add some of the pertinent info from that link to your answer?

Comment: This also makes the assumption that things like walking and talking followed the same developmental timeline back then that they do now. For all we know walking and talking were instantaneous or took 20 years. It's impossible to tell. The ibex can run immediately after birth. Perhaps evolutionally because it had to. Maybe humans didn't have to in the beginning and everything took it's time slowly. Adaptation beginning at zero.

Comment: we are on a site based around Christianity and you are talking about survival of the fittest and adaption. I don't see that we could compare ourselves to an ibex? do we look like an ibex?